# Generate table with row numbers postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create a temp table with just row numbers generated. I do not have any source table to pull data from.

For example, I need to create a column named index with 1-50 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
create table t (id int);

with recursive
x (n) as (
  select 1
 union all
  select n + 1 from x where n < 50
)
insert into t (id)
select n from x;
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cJM16a2epSM364L3KqdwYW/0).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html).  But don't use the name `index` because that is a SQL keyword so it is a very bad choice for a column name:

```
select gs.i
from generate_series(1, 50, 1) gs(i);
```

Comment: @kash . . . Is there a reason that you unaccepted this answer.  `generate_series()` is really the better way to do what you want.